# MySQL Crippling performance - indexes

Tags: mysql

Just wondering if anyone knows a quick way to check the health of some indexes on a table. The one we are having trouble with is quite a large table, but it has indexes so *should* be ok ("show indexes from mytable" shows them as present).

But it's going really slowly whenever we try to access this table, so wondering if we need to rebuild the indexes or something. None of us here are DBA's so really really appreicate any tips, it's getting quite urgent :(

It's a MyISAM table by the way, dumped from a v4 DB to a v5 database.

Thanks

Comment: What is slow? Reading, writing, or both? What indices do you have?

Comment: Can you post your table structure and the queries which are slow?

Answer (score 1):

- [Check Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html)
- Turn on [slow query logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) if it's not already on.
- Run [`explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execution-plan-information.html) on the slow queries to investigate why they're running slow.

Comment: Thanks, I've followed your advice and run a check table (extended) and it seems to be OK. Will check the slow query logging next, thanks. Emil, Arkh, it's reads and writes. I'll try and get the structure up for you soon. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Do post the explain plans of your slowest running queries.

Comment: Hi we're still frantically trying to fix this but have some more information. The performance is good when we do a query that uses 'filesort' rather than an index. The indexes seems to be slowing things down. Also, setting a low limit (limit 1) have a huge performance hit. If we run the same query with a high limit (limit 10000) the performance is great. Will try to get some explain plans for more info but appreciate any more thoughts.

Comment: Please add this information along with your table structure and explain plans to your question. I'm not a a DB tuning expert :) I'll try to analyze your plans when you post them.

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM tables does not always update index distribution information. Because of this sometimes we need to do it manually: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Thanks, I ran the analyze and it said everything was fine for the tables in question. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Richard So as I understand, the performance of your queries hasn't changed after you ran analyze, yes? It would be useful to see your queries, indexes and explain plans.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, really appreciate it (I know it's a week or so ago since I posted this, been a very busy time...). It turned out to be that the indexes were fine, but were disabled. We think it happened because when we took a backup, the backup crashed half way through. Apparently a backup disables the indexes, then re-enables them afterwards. Since it crashed, they never got re-enabled. Once we turned them back on, it's super quick, phew....

Hope that's useful for someone else